# Difference between criterion of k-means?

Tags: k-means

I am watching a video on k-means clustering here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLf0Z9tCTjE&index=30&list=PL3DFCC23FCE3C7EFB, in which (12:14) the professor briefly mentioned some criterion other than the standard "minimizing within-cluster sum of squares".

[image]
[image]

Will these criterion yield the same result? If not, what is the difference among them and what are their advantages over "minimizing within-cluster sum of squares"? Thank you!

Comment: It looks like a fine question, but so that all readers will understand it in the same way--and in the same way you do--please edit this post to include definitions of $S_W$, $S_B$, and $\hat\Sigma$.  (It does not suffice to require readers to watch a video in order to understand the question!)

Comment: All these criterions can be seen as various versions of normalizing tr(Sw), the within-cluster SS. There exist much more than those three.